# Cox Regression When Event is Uncertain

Tags: cox-model

Hypothetical Situation:

I'm trying to create a cox model on data set with some serious quality issues. Sometimes the event goes unreported in our data set. Some patients have a treatment regime that makes it look as if the event took place but there is no actual event recorded. I was able to examine about 25 of these patients closely and I determined 10 did not have the event, 15 did. There are about 100 more of these patients in the dataset.

When I say that all these patients had an event the model looks better in terms of concordance and the frequency of events is more in line with other populations.

Is there some way I can incorporate uncertainty? Is it better to introduce false positives than leave in false negatives?